# Что значит число 4.47e+8 ?

Tags: числа

Что значит число 4.47e+8 ?

Comment: Архимеда знаете? Так вот это его методика записи сколь угодно длинных чисел. Если вам напишут число 4.47e+8 в нормальной десятичной форме, то это будет слишком длинно.

Comment: [Read The Fine Manual](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C)

Comment: `4.47e+8` -- `447000000`. `4.47e+8` -> `4.47 * 10 ^ 8`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Это число **447 000 000**. Или **4.47 × 10<sup>8</sup>**. Так удобнее писать на компьютере.

Вот ответ [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4.47e%2B8)

Answer (score 5):

Обычный снос разрядов в числе. Когда **записывается 4,47 · 10^8, подразумевается снос плавающей запятой на 8 разрядов вперёд** — в данном случае **это** будет число **447 с 6 нулями впереди, т.е. 447.000.000**. В программировании могут использоваться E-значения, причём **e нельзя писать само по себе**, но **E — можно (но не везде и не всегда, об этом будет отмечено ниже), т.к. предпоследнее может ошибочно принятым за число Эйлера**. Если нужно записать огромное число сокращённо, может использоваться стиль 4,47·E8 (альтернативный вариант для производства и мелкошрифтной печати — 4,47×E8), чтобы число читалось более разгружено и разряды указывались более обособленно (между арифметическими знаками ставить пробелы нельзя — в противном случае, это математическое условие, а не число).

3,52E3 — это хорошо для записи без индексов, но читать разрядное смещение будет сложнее. 3,52 · 10^8 — условие, т.к. требует индекса и отсутствует мантисса (последнее существует только у оператора, а это — расширенный множитель). ' · 10' — процесс стандартного (основного) операционного умножения, число после ^ — показатель сноса разрядов, поэтому его не нужно делать мелким, если необходимо писать документы в данной форме (соблюдая надстрочное положение), в некоторых случаях, желательно использовать масштаб в районе 100 - 120%, а не стандартные 58%. Используя мелкий масштаб для ключевых элементов условия, снижается визуальное качество цифровой информации — придётся всматриваться (может быть и не нужно, но факт остаётся фактом — «прятать» условия мелким шрифтом не нужно, можно было вообще «закопать» — сокращать масштаб отдельных элементов условия это неприемлемо, особенно на компьютере), чтобы заметить «сюрприз», а это очень вредно даже на бумажном ресурсе.

Если процесс умножения выполняет особые операции, то в таких случаях использование пробелов может быть избыточным, т.к. помимо умножения чисел, множитель может быть связывающим звеном для огромных и мелких чисел, химэлементов и т.д. и т.п., которые нельзя записать десятичной дробью обычных чисел или невозможно записать конечным результатом. Это может не касаться записи с ' · 10^y', т.к. любое значение в выражении выполняет роль множителя, а '^y' — степень, указываемая надстрочным способом, т.е. является числовым условием. Но, убрав пробелы вокруг множителя и записав иначе — будет ошибкой, т.к. оператор отсутствует. Сам отрывок записи ' · 10' — множитель-оператор + число, а не первый + второй оператор. Здесь и есть основная причина того, почему с 10-кой так нельзя. Если после числового оператора нет особых значений, т.е. нечисловых, но системных, то данный вариант записи не может быть оправдан — если есть системное значение, то такое значение должно подходить под определённые задачи с числовым или практическим сокращением чисел (для определённых действий, например, 1,35f8, где f — какое-либо уравнение, созданное для практических специальных задач, которое выводит действительные числа в результате конкретных практических опытов, 8 — значение, которое подставлено как переменное к оператору f и совпадает с числами при последовательном изменении условий наиболее удобным образом, если эта задача архиважная, то такие данные значения могут быть использованы со знаком без пробелов). Кратко, для подобных арифметических операций, но с другими целями, также можно проделывать с плюсами, минусами и делителями, если в этом есть крайняя необходимость для создания новых или упрощения существующих способов записи данных с сохранением точности на практике и может являться применимым числовым условием для определённых арифметических целей.

Итог: официально утверждённую форму экспоненциальной записи рекомендуется писать с пробелом и масштабом надстрочного шрифта в 58% и смещением в 33% (если изменение масштаба и смещения разрешается другими сторонами уровень в 100 - 120%, то можно установить 100% — это самый оптимальный вариант записи надстрочных значений, оптимальное смещение — ≈ 50%). На компьютере можно использовать 3,74e+2, 4,58E-1, 6,73·E-5, E-11, если последние два формата поддерживаются, на форумах лучше отказаться от e-сокращений по известным причинам, а стиль 3,65·E-5 или 5,67E4 может быть полностью понятным, исключения могут составлять лишь **официальные сегменты общественности** — там **только с ' · 10^x**', причём **вместо ^x — используется только надстрочная запись степени**.

Короче говоря, **E является суперсокращением для десятичного антилогарифма, который часто помечают, как antilog** либо **antilg.** Например, 7,947antilg-4 будет равен тому же, что и 7,947E-4. На практике это гораздо практичнее и удобнее, чем тягать «десятку» с надстрочным знаком степени лишний раз. Это можно назвать «экспоненциальным» логарифмическим видом числа как альтернативный вариант менее удобному «экспоненциальному» классическому. Только вместо «antilg», используется «E» либо сразу идёт второе число с пропуском (если число положительное) либо без него (на десятисегментных научных калькуляторах, типа "Citizen CT-207T").

Answer (score 2):

Говоря по простому

100000000 = 1Е + 08,

1000000000 = 1Е + 09

итд

Answer (score 0):

Когда увидел такое правило. Просто при чтении буква е (которая от слова экспонента пошла) читается как "умножить на десять в степени" и все будет понятно.

Comment: Нуу, для обезображенных математикой e все-таки читается не как 10, а как число Эйлера...

Comment: А американы (IBM) может ничего про Эйлера и не знали... Правда когда они такое сочинили, была буква "E". "е" появилась десятилетия спустя. (На советских БПУ, т.е. ещё до АЦПУ была 10 в регистре индекса).

Comment: @alexlz, хех, не знал таких подробностей; думал что это пошло от восьмисегментных цифровых дисплеев.